# Add fields to PFAnonymousUtils BEFORE logInWithBlock

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfuser

I want to create an anonymous user on Parse.
I would like that anonymous user to have a field for 'language' which will save the device's default language.
My PFUser object has a field 'language'.

Is there a way to save `[PFUser current][@"language"]` BEFORE calling `logInWithBlock`??

Or do I have to wait for the completion block and then save a second time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone swiftly answered on the official Parse GitHub Page: 
[PFAnonymousUtils w/ fields](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/204#issuecomment-138770386)